# Bootstrap grid - center divs and blurbs in middle

Tags: css, layout

I am having an issue of using bootstrap grid system for a specific layout. I would like to create a center div that would contain 6 products[image].. However i cannon achieve the example in the photo. Can anyone provide the code of how to achieve the result that i show in the photo?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your code or even better a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/hyo2gaap/

Comment: Did you try it on larger viewport? Because as it seems working normal to me [(screenshot)](http://i.imgur.com/M9KUHO6.png)

Comment: Ok thanks for your replies i have made some changes and it working perfect now